# Hierarchical LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I want to predict the next element of a sequence using Lstm in Keras. I want to use hierarchical Lstm but not standard stacking. I want to implement two-layer lstm like below image (in the first layer there is *time_step* lstm unroll and in the second row only exist for example 3 lstm unroll) 
[image]

how can I implement in usinig functional API in keras?